# Binding 2 cells in a table view (swift 4)

Tags: xcode, tableview, swift4, cells, rx-swift

I couldn't find any answer for that so I'm creating this topic.

I have a table view inside my UI view and through my viewController I'm binding the main view and registering and trying to bind the cells, so I did this:

```
    private func bindCells() {
    viewModel.address.asObservable()
        .bind(to: TableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: AccountShippingCell.Identifier, cellType: AccountShippingCell.self))                           {
            row, address, cell in
            cell.address = address
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
    viewModel.payment.asObservable()
        .bind(to: TableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: AccountPaymentCell.Identifier, cellType: AccountPaymentCell.self))                           {
            row, payment, cell in
            cell.payment = payment
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

But It crash all time closing my Xcode. I understood that when passing identifier + cell type I was already making it different. but it seems to be competing to register.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what crash? share the message.

Comment: Even xcode closes and debugging I see some "concurrent" message. If I comment this second bind nothing happens. Not sure id there's a safe way to bind twice for a single table view. Really would like to know how.

Comment: Update: I tried collections too, unsuccessfully...

Comment: Use `RxDataSources`. You cannot (should not) bind twice to the tableview's items.

Comment: Thanks Valérian. I'll go check that then. I tried 2 different table views but it's ugly anyways.

Comment: SO I ended doing it with collection and I thought it was much easier